# Search S3 bucket for files of specific extension

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the AWS Java SDK. I have a S3 bucket who's name is known and has about 100 files. I am trying to retrieve those files whose extension is ".zip". 
As far as I see I don't see any API which let's you search an S3 bucket.

The format I was using was:

```
ListObjectsV2Result result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(new ListObjectsV2Request()
    .withBucketName(bucketName)
    .withDelimeter(".zip"));
```

Weirdly, this returns all the files which do not have a ".zip" extension. Is there some sort of filter I can use? To extend the question, can I filter out options like ".zip.bak" from the ".zip extension?

Thanks!

Comment: Currently, there is no way to do this using official SDKs. "Delimiter", in this context, is not what you think it means.